# Setting word wrap on QLabel breaks size constrains for the window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

TEXT = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " \
       "Nullam malesuada tellus in ex elementum, vitae rutrum enim vestibulum."

#==============================================================================
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Widgets
        self.label = QLabel(TEXT, self) 
#         self.label.setWordWrap(True)    
        self.text = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text.setMinimumSize(480, 320)
        self.text.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        # Layout
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text, 1, 0)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.layout.setSpacing(5)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)   

        self.adjustSize()
        self.show()           

#==============================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works as expected, producing a window, which cannot be resized to be smaller:

[image]

However, when I uncomment the `self.label.setWordWrap(True)` line, these constrains seem to disappear. I can resize the window to smaller, completely breaking the layout, as `QTextEdit` still retains its size constrain:

[image]

I tried to fix this using `self.setMinimumSize(self.size())`. This works for this particular example, however breaks if the size is bigger, such as `self.text.setMinimumSize(480, 800)`. That makes the window too small even when it is being created, so `setMinimumSize` does not help:

[image]

Is there a way how to fix it and make the window / layout still match the minimum size of `QTextEdit` even when word wrap is enabled?

Version information:

```
OS: Windows-7-SP1 (32bit)
Python: 3.4.1
PyQt: 5.3.1
Qt: 5.3.1
```

Comment: This issue is mentioned in the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues). There is also a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37673).

Comment: @thuga - Wow! Thanks. I would not expect this.

Comment: @thuga the bug report link is missing, perhaps it's this one: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37673

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @thuga suggested in a comment the problem is mentioned in [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues) and already [reported](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37673), apparently with "won't / can't fix" resolution.

I have found a hint for a workaround for this particular problem [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8766-Qt-layouting-QLabel-s-word-wrap-bug). It works for my example and also my application:
`self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())`.

The code then looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

TEXT = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " \
       "Nullam malesuada tellus in ex elementum, vitae rutrum enim vestibulum."

#==============================================================================
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Widgets
        self.label = QLabel(TEXT, self) 
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)    
        self.text = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text.setMinimumSize(480, 800)
        self.text.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        # Layout
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text, 1, 0)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.layout.setSpacing(5)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)   

        self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())
        self.show()     

#==============================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, with QT 4.8, and I couldn't upgrade my QT, since I was working on a plugin of QGIS 2.18 that still use QT 4.8.

My work around is manipulating the `maximumHeight` of the `QWebView` (or in your case, your `QTextEdit`) when the resize happen. You will need to emit custom signal for resized, since it's not available in QT (see: [PyQt: Detect resizing in Widget-window resized signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126721/pyqt-detect-resizing-in-widget-window-resized-signal/43126946#43126946))

So, my code is something like this:

```
class MetadataConverterDialog(QDialog):
    resized = pyqtSignal()
        # Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43126946/1198772
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        """Emit custom signal when the window is re-sized.

        :param event: The re-sized event.
        :type event: QResizeEvent
        """
        self.resized.emit()
        return super(MetadataConverterDialog, self).resizeEvent(event)

    def after_resize(self):
        """Method after resizing the window."""
        max_height = self.height() - 275  # Magic number, to make it pretty
        self.metadata_preview_web_view.setMaximumHeight(max_height)
```

The 275 is the value that I need to spare to show the dialog properly (for the widget before the QWebView. You will need to find the value that fits with your dialog.