# Detect resizing in Widget-window resized signal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

I create a simple UI with Qt Designer and convert it to Python codes. I searched for any method to detect changing window size.

This is the generated code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def onResize(event):
        print(event)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        MainWindow.resized.connect(self.someFunction)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I found a similar question [QWidget resize signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955780/qwidget-resize-signal) and [this tutorial to handle size](http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?index=360&key=QMainWindowResizeEvent) that recommended overriding *resizeEvent* method of *QMainWindow*.

But any of them doesn't solve my problem. Is there any **resized** function to detect window resizing like below:

```
MainWindow.resized.connect(self.someFunction)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no such signal by default, but you can create the `resized` signal, we emit it in the `resizeEvent` function.

For Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    resized = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def  __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        self.resized.connect(self.someFunction)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.resized.emit()
        return super(Window, self).resizeEvent(event)

    def someFunction(self):
        print("someFunction")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why the `return super(...)`? `resizeEvent` does not return anything according to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent

Comment: @user136036 Every function returns something even if that something is "nothing", for example you can use `void foo(){ return; }` or simply `void foo(){}`, the use or not use of return is stylistic and optional in a method that returns nothing.

Comment: Such functions which do not have a return statement in them are called void functions. Void functions are those that do not return anything. 'None' is a special type in Python which is returned after a void function ends. So technically, it would always return `None`, but really, it doesn't return anything.